# complicated quotes with javascript and php

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, attributes

I have a function with I have to give parameter jQuery selectors. My problem starts when I need to give something like that `'[name="ElementNameHere"]'` quotes in quotes... 
PHP function returns JavaScript, so it is a string and there is more quotes.
It looks something like that:

```
<?php
function myFunction( $selector ) {
    $string = "<script> $( '$selector' ).myFunction(); </script>";
    return $string;
}
myFunction( '[name="ElementNameHere"]' );
```

Well now it breaks string apart because what happening is

```
$string = " $('[name="ElementNameHere"]').myFunction()";
```

And if I put `'\'` as I call it, it just doesnt do for me. is there some way to avoid this?

Comment: I don't see a problem with the value of `$string`.

Comment: What happened to `<script>` and `</script>` inside `$string`?

Comment: Seems to work for me: http://www.tehplayground.com/#yXKeF5aFg

Comment: @Barmar `ElementNameHere` is not inside the string.
@user255572 But escaping " (and not ') should work

Comment: `myFunction` would actually be valid JS and PHP, might I suggest not using the dollar sign in JS?

Comment: $RPM The `$` in JS is for jQuery.

Comment: @Lithy Why isn't `ElementNameHere` inside the string? When you substitute variables it doesn't re-scan the result for quotes, so the quotes inside the variable don't cause a problem.

Comment: @user255572 Please show more of the application, and show how this is causing problems. The problem isn't in the code you posted, it's probably in the way you're using the result.

Comment: I dont have ready script for this. I tried to write it couple of days ago and ended up giving it additional parameter that says that first parameter is name. And it works okey. I was just wondering. :)

Comment: Looking at esqew link, seems like I really messed up. Thanks you guys.

Answer (score 0):

Your method is not working actually like you want,

your are not actually embedding the `$selector` parameter on you're $string, cause you are just setting a full string to that variable, try to do

```
$string = "<script> $( '".$selector."' ).myFunction(); </script>";
```

Remember you need to concat the strings with the var.

try to fix this, and this solve your quotes problem cause the var casts to an string.